# Не рабоает count()

Tags: c#

Не работает функция count(). Она должна искать в массиве числа которые совпадают с введеным.Но всега выдает 0.Помогите раобраться

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter digit(30 MAX): ");
        int digit=Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        int[] arr = new int[30];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = rnd.Next(0,30);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(arr[i]+" ");
        int sum = arr.Count(p => p == digit);
        Console.Write($"\n\nCount = {sum}\n\n\n");


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в `Console.Read()`.

Эта функция возвращает вам **число**, код одного введённого символа. Поэтому в `digit` будет не то число, которое вы ввели, а его код.

Номера видимых символов начинаются от 0x20 == 32, и поскольку числа в массиве лежат в промежутке от 0 до 29, ни одно число найдено и правда не будет.

---

Попробуйте заменить `Console.Read()` на `Console.ReadLine()`.

---

P. S.: Если вы научитесь пользоваться отладчиком, такие вопросы будут решаться влёт без «помощи клуба».